# Ember: How do I get simple form data without a model?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to do get a single string from a form input and log it to the console. Is there a way to do this without using an Ember Data model?

Here's the form component in Handlebars:

```
// my-form.hbs
<form {{action "grabNewEmail" on="submit"}}>
  {{input value="Your Email Address"}}
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Get Early Access</button>
</form>
```

And here's the current code from the component:

```
// my-form.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    grabNewEmail() {
      let email = /* I want to get this string from the input on submit */
      console.log(email);
    }
  }
});
```

Is it possible to simply grab the input string, or am I required to create a model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a model, you can use a component property to store and retrieve the data.

In your hbs:

```
{{input value=newEmailAddress}}
```

And in your component you can do:

```
export default Ember.component.extend({
    newEmailAddress: "",  // Not really needed, just to be explicit that this variable exists in the component.
    actions: {
        grabNewEmail () {
            let email = this.get('newEmailAddress');
        }
    }
});
```